# Opencv - object detection with tracking - how to set up?

Tags: opencv, svm, feature-detection, video-tracking

I am trying to do an object recognition with OpenCV. The idea is that I start with an empty database and subsequently add objects into it with a camera. 
So far I have a tracking algorithm which is based on the opencv method calcOpticalFlowPyrLK and a matching algorithm.

What I am now not sure about is, how to set up the database.

My idea is the following:

I am detecting SIFT feature points (lets say frame1 1000 FeaturePoints(FPs)) in the first frame. In the subsequent frame2 I am taking over the features I recognized in frame1 due to the tracking algorithm (say 500). With this 500 I go to frame3 and take over those FPs I can track from frame2 (say 400) and so on. 
This means that the number of feature points in constantly dropping over the frames.

Therefore I want to introduce two thresholds of say 100FPs and 40FPs. If I undergo 100Fps (assume this happens in frame6) - then I start to detect again SIFT features in frame6 and push the points with that back to 1000.
Unless the drop is so high that I do not only undergo 100 FPs but also 40FPs in frame6 then I consider this frame to show a new Object.

Let's say I have to refresh my FPs every 6 frames and after 7 refreshs I drop below 40 and want to classify the object. This means I have recognized 7000 Fps for Object 1. But many of them are very similar or even the same. Therefore I thought about putting this FPs into an SVM to learn the object. 
Now the question is what kind of SVM is the best for my purpose. I cannot do a "negative training", means I have no images which are showing the wrong object to train the classifier. I could do that once I have detected a few objects.

I hope my problem became clear and somebody can give me inspiration or good advice how to proceed.

Best Regards

Comment: It looks like you want to make analogue of the TLD-tracker (http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/tld.html) , but with SIFTs instead of LBP (much slower) and SVM instead of random ferns (much more slow in learning). Are you sure that it is good idea?

Comment: Neither SVM's or Ferns will work without negative samples. I would suggest you pre-populate some samples with expected background information and then try to train a classifier.. All classifiers have their merits; you need to try out different things (maybe read up a little on each of them) and find which suits your needs the best.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! The TLD-tracker is pretty much what I'm looking for. I'll try to learn something about the used techniques that I can apply for my problem.